# Could not find driver (Connection: MySQL, SQL: select * from `invoices`) laravel - vue project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, laragon

I tried to send the data from the database to the front-end (laravel-vue) I use laragon and PHP 8.1.22.
Steps that I follow to send data:

1. I add this script to ../resources/js/components/Invoice/index.vue

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted , ref } from 'vue';
let invoices = ref([])
const getInvoices = async () => {
    let response = await axios.get("/api/get_all_invoice")
    console.log('response' , response)
}
onMounted(async() => {
    getInvoices()
})
</script>
```

1. In the  ../routes/api.php

   ```php
   use App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController;
   Route::get('/get_all_invoice',[InvoiceController::class,'get_all_invoice']);
   ```
2. go to the controller and add the function `get_all_invoice`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Invoice;

class InvoiceController extends Controller
{
    public function get_all_invoice(){
        $invoices = Invoice::all();
        return response()->json([
            'invoice'=>$invoices
        ],200);
    }
}
```

To solve this problem I tried to enable the `extension=pdo_mysql  extension=pdo_pgsql`
in the php.ini  for the PHP 8.1.22 in laragon folders and I restart laragon but I have no result.

When I add this code:

```php
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

To welcome.blade.php  and I searched about pdo in the table said no value for pdo  drivers  is that mean that the pdo is not enabled or is that the default setting?

Comment: If you visit `get_all_invoice` in the browser, what do you see?

Comment: @ceejayoz could not find driver
SELECT * FROM `invoices`
and a red line on this line of code         $invoices = Invoice::all();
this line is in the InvoiceController.php

Comment: What OS is used there?

Comment: @Tpojka windows

Comment: have you tried restarting your xampp? You said you added extensions. apache needs to reload to take effect

Comment: hy @Mr.Kenneth  I use laragon yes after I enable those extensions I restart it but it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

hy finally it worked I changed the script for getting the data and I restarted Laragon and vs code too

```js
onMounted(() => {
  axios.get('/api/get_all_invoice')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data); 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you previous code was not working for you because you are not awaiting `getInvoices` function in `onMounted` hook